# SQL Server Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want give value in table Customer set Status = 'A' on one individu

How to query where table mastersales have related with table Customer?

Attribute and value MasterSales

Example Company : ABC Company (ms001)

```
mastersales : ms001 (primarykey)
Customer    : cu0112, cu113,cu114,cu116,cu117

mastersales : ms002 (primarykey)
Customer    : cu0115
```

so i want to update customer set status = 'A' where customer = mastersales `ms001 (cu0112, cu113,cu114,cu116,cu117 )`

Comment: Can you provide full schema of both tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE c
    SET status = 'A'
    FROM Customer c
    INNER JOIN Mastersales m ON c.customer = m.customer 
    WHERE m.mastersales = 'ms001';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update tablename set status = 'A' where customer in (select customer  from tablename where mastersales =ms001);
```

Comment: i am not sure why it was DV,but customer = (select ) seems wrong to me  in case of mutiple result sets